# Differences Between Iterator and Generator in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, iterator, generator

I need help in differentiating iterators and generators in TypeScript.

Resource Link: https://courses.edx.org/courses/course-v1:Microsoft+DEV273x+1T2019/courseware/d2b1e6e94b0b46528fbff396a486c045/6a959ce8b5cf40c38d3f4f4e0b737603/1?activate_block_id=block-v1%3AMicrosoft%2BDEV273x%2B1T2019%2Btype%40vertical%2Bblock%40994a937b62b746eaadfbf20382b4615b

"Iterators are basically objects that can hold more than one item. Iterators are collections of objects or variables or items that can be iterated on to do some sort of processing on each item in the collection. Arrays are an example of iterators. In TypeScript, an object is deemed iterable if it has an implementation for the Symbol.iterator property. 
Code example:

```
let someArray = [1, "string", false];

for (let entry of someArray) {
    console.log(entry); // 1, "string", false
}

let list = [4, 5, 6];

for (let i in list) {
   console.log(i); // "0", "1", "2", the keys of the array are the indices of its items
}

for (let i of list) {
   console.log(i); // "4", "5", "6"
}
```

Generators
Targeting ES5 and ES3
When targeting an ES5 or ES3, iterators are only allowed on values of Array type. It is an error to use for..of loops on non-Array values, even if these non-Array values implement the Symbol.iterator property.

The compiler will generate a simple for loop for a for..of loop, for instance:

```
let numbers = [1, 2, 3];
for (let num of numbers) {
    console.log(num);
}
```

will be generated as:

```
var numbers = [1, 2, 3];
for (var _i = 0; _i < numbers.length; _i++) {
    var num = numbers[_i];
    console.log(num);
}
```

Targeting ECMAScript 2015 and higher
When targeting an ECMAScipt 2015-compliant engine, the compiler will generate for..of loops to target the built-in iterator implementation in the engine. "

The reason I was confused: both iterator and generator use array and for loop as example. It also seems that they have certain relationships in TypeScript.

Could someone help me in identifying the differences between iterator and generator in TypeScript?

Comment: I mean, it's literally the first result if you Google `javascript iterator generator`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Iterators_and_Generators

Comment: Hi Kemp, are you saying that Iterator and Generator in TypeScript are the same as in JavaScript?